# TFS "The item ... may not be cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent."

Tags: eclipse, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm working with TFS 2013 via the TFS Server plug-in for Eclipse (Team Explorer Everywhere v14.0.1).

We have two branches of a project, a master and a release. Each has a DEV folder (containing application.properties, logback.xml, etc ) in which environment configuration is maintained. The folder was initially placed in source control to allow new members to pull everything they need in one shot. Now, however this seems burdensome to established team members as when trying to switch between branches, the error

> The item $/projectName/project-branchName/src.../DEV may not be
>   cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent.

To switch branches, one must uncloak any cloaked folders to continue. I have since deleted folders which contain dev configurations or those which should stay out of source control.

However, I'd like to know is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use and edit a single workspace when trying to "switch" branches?

If so, **the recommended approach is to use two different workspaces**, one for each branch, and then switch between workspaces.

The reason for this can be best illustrated with an example:

Imagine your workspace contains two mappings:

map $/projectName/project-branchName/src some-local-path

cloak $/projectName/project-branchName/src.../DEV

and by “switching” you mean that you edit the workspace mappings and change project-branchName from *master* to *release* or vice versa. This is a typical catch-22. If you change the branch name in the first mapping first, you immediately get an error because the second mapping tries to cloak a folder in the old branch, which is not mapped anymore. If you first change the branch name in the second mapping, you get an error because the mapping tries to cloak a folder in the new branch, which is not mapped yet.

Not sure this fully answers your question.  If not, please feel free to provide a little more explanation of what you are attempting to do and we'll see if we can better assist!

Thanks!

Comment: I take it that the cloaking configurations are not preserved for individual branches, but rather in the TFS workspace to blanket any branch. I was hoping to stick to the ability to switch branches (Team > Switch to Branch) similar to Git due to convenience, but that does provide an alternative. Much appreciated.